# Notifying actual owner after references count of Obj reaches zero

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

The case is:

Imagine a manager that is responsible for creating and holding different kind of abstract resources (pseudocode)

```
class ResourcesManager { 
    fun Ref<ResourceA> createResourceA();
    fun Ref<ResourceB> createResourceB();
    
    private:
        container<ResourceA> aResources;
        container<ResourceB> bResources;
}
```

When the manager creates a new resource, it saves it inside and exposes it outside to caller through some sort of shared pointer (Ref<...>).

What I want to accomplish is *to not delete the resource Obj when its count in Ref reaches 0*. Instead, the actual owner (ResourcesManager) should be notified about it (it means that no one use
that resource anymore).
So ResourcesManager can decide what to do next, it can just delete the resource obj and remove from container, or it can just mark that this resource is free to use and later, when some one wants to create the same resource, it can be taken from the container instead of creating a new one.

*What ways to do that?*

shared_ptr calls *delete* itself after it reaches 0.

So apparently I need my own version of shared pointer that does not deletes itself, but which notifies the owner when no one use Obj anymore.
Is that a right way?

Comment: You could have a shared_ptr to a wrapper. The wrapper keeps only a public reference to the actual object. In its destructor the wrapper notifies the manager. You can also overload * and -> of the wrapper. Than it acts like a smart pointer.

Comment: It sounds like you're building a garbage collector. Maybe you can achieve this using a different allocator for your shared_ptr. You could look into the std::pmr allocators, or write a custom one. Note, C++ is not a memory managed language like C#, and attempts to make it similar will result in disappointment, as it will give bad performance. It's a different language with a different purpose.

Comment: No need to do anything fancy, just have a custom deleter on the shared pointer

Comment: @alanbirtles that would only be useful for handing ownership to the "resource manager" right? You'd still have to build that yourself. I was suggesting to use a (combination of) pmr allocator(s) to realize the resource manager, e.g. a pool allocator.

Comment: Thanks for helping.

You are all right. Resources Manager really looks like a Pool Allocator. And custom deleter looks like what i need for now (didn't know about custom deleters).

So i would use a custom deleter just for now, and next step is custom or std predefined pool allocator.

Answer (score 1):

So based on the comments I've decided to use custom deleter in std shared pointer.

But eventually i will create my own pool allocator and custom pointer so i can write more specific memory management for my application